# svn checkout prompt for store user name and password after and before the svn checkout?

Tags: svn-checkout

svn checkout prompt for store user name and password
after and before the svn checkout?

how to provide yes in the same command,
then for next time this should not be prompt for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am npt remember ing the exact file name may be dblock in your repository and change the value of

```
anonymous -user
```